# Access object private propoerties

Tags: web-services, symfony, soap

i would like to access to the protected propertie **parcelNumber**

```
TNTExpress\Model\Expedition Object  
(  
    [parcelResponses:protected] => Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection Object  
        (  
            [elements:Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection:private] => Array  
                (  
                    [0] => TNTExpress\Model\ParcelResponse Object  
                        (  
                            [sequenceNumber:protected] => 1  
                            [parcelNumber:protected] => 9112758000000006 
                            [trackingURL:protected] => http://www.tnt.fr/public/suivi_colis/recherche/visubontransport.do?bonTransport=9112345000000006  
                            [stickerNumber:protected] =>   
                        )  
                )  
        )
```

what should i do ?

Comment: Probably something like $expedition->getParcelResponses()[0]->getParcelNumber();  And please don't come back it say it did not work without providing some details of what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two basic options:

- Because its protected you can extend the class, and add new getter (if library is possible to extend)
- Or you can use reflection to get your info - http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.getvalue.php

With reflection it will be something like this:

```
$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass(YourClass::class);
$reflectionProperty = $reflectionClass->getProperty('parcelResponses');
$reflectionProperty->setAccessible(true); // change it to public
var_dump($reflectionProperty->getValue($yourInstance)); // You get you value
```

Comment: i tryed with reflexion that i did not know before, and next i found a better solution with the getter. thank you M. Kebza